# Calculate new list with differences of list elements

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a faster way to calculate the absolute difference between every element of two lists.

This is my current code, but it gets a bit slow with big arrays:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
x_values = np.random.randint(-50,100,size=(10))
test_values = x_values * 2
# print(x_values, test_values)
for x in test_values:
    test = sorted([(j, np.abs(j-x)) for j in x_values], key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(test)
```

Output:

```
[(-37, 37), (-17, 57), (4, 78), (12, 86), (27, 101), (38, 112), (50, 124), (57, 131), (72, 146), (76, 150)]
[(-37, 3), (-17, 17), (4, 38), (12, 46), (27, 61), (38, 72), (50, 84), (57, 91), (72, 106), (76, 110)]
[(12, 4), (4, 4), (27, 19), (-17, 25), (38, 30), (50, 42), (-37, 45), (57, 49), (72, 64), (76, 68)]
[(27, 3), (12, 12), (38, 14), (4, 20), (50, 26), (57, 33), (-17, 41), (72, 48), (76, 52), (-37, 61)]
[(57, 3), (50, 4), (38, 16), (72, 18), (76, 22), (27, 27), (12, 42), (4, 50), (-17, 71), (-37, 91)]
[(76, 0), (72, 4), (57, 19), (50, 26), (38, 38), (27, 49), (12, 64), (4, 72), (-17, 93), (-37, 113)]
[(76, 24), (72, 28), (57, 43), (50, 50), (38, 62), (27, 73), (12, 88), (4, 96), (-17, 117), (-37, 137)]
[(76, 38), (72, 42), (57, 57), (50, 64), (38, 76), (27, 87), (12, 102), (4, 110), (-17, 131), (-37, 151)]
[(76, 68), (72, 72), (57, 87), (50, 94), (38, 106), (27, 117), (12, 132), (4, 140), (-17, 161), (-37, 181)]
[(76, 76), (72, 80), (57, 95), (50, 102), (38, 114), (27, 125), (12, 140), (4, 148), (-17, 169), (-37, 189)]
```

Comment: If you want difference between every element of two lists, then complexity would be O(n^2), no matter of the code.

Comment: Can you provide the code for it?

Comment: Would it be okay to have a multi-dim array of shape `(10,10,2)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure numpy solution. I didn't compare it against your code in terms of speed, so let me know:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
x_values = np.random.randint(-50,100,size=(10))
test_values = x_values*2

# create a matrix of len(test_values) times the test_values column vector...
test_mat = np.array([test_values]*len(test_values)).T

# ... and then calculate the absolute difference matrix
abs_mat = np.abs(x_values - test_mat)

# this part is to obtain your desired output
output = np.column_stack((np.array([x_values]*len(x_values)).flatten(), abs_mat.flatten()))
output = np.split(output, len(x_values))
```